# PHP Queing background processes

Tags: php, background-process

What is the best way to queue background processes in PHP...

Zend's job queue seems very nice but I am not able to switch to zend server what are the alternatives for doing this?

Comment: I mean Zend Platform Job Queue (long name).. Zend Queue with Zend Cache looks interesting though..

Answer (score 1):

[Gearman](http://gearman.org/) is very capable.  [Here's the PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman), and [here's a process monitor / daemon](http://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager).

There's also things like the [Amazon Simple Queue Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).